# Bluetooth from Service in android

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-service

In my application,Im using a BroadcastReceiver,which fires a service class,after checking the phone state RINGING.In the service class,Im disabling Wifi and bluetooth after checking a status flag from a database.I can change the Wifi state;but exception comes when i try the same for Bluetooth.

Can anybody suggest a way to use the BluetoothAdapter inside a service???

DatabaseServic is my service class and this is the primary exception i receive in the logcat...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.radiationreducer.DatabaseService: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
         {
             System.out.println("inside bluetooth iffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                Toast.makeText(DatabaseService.this, "BLUETOOTH DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO bluetoothflag VALUES ('"+RESET+"');");
                myDB.delete("bluetoothflag", null, null);
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO bluetoothflag VALUES ('"+RESET+"');");
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO bluetoothflag VALUES ('"+SET+"');");
                System.out.println("inside bluetooth ifffffffffendddddddddd");
         }
```

Please suggest any other method to turn off Bluetooth programmatically...

Answer (score -1):

You are using the BluetoothAdapter in your service! (And it works...)

Your error is somewhere else in the code:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service**
com.android.radiationreducer.DatabaseService: java.lang.NullPointerException

Maybe you forgot to add the service to the manifest(common mistake)?